# How to get the value from an input in an li using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

**How to get values dropdown ul. show console ?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3YLt.png)

```
<div class="card-tools">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <ul class="prod-gram" id="language">
         <li class="init">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ App::getLocale() }}"/>
            <img class="border border-secondary" src='{{ asset('/') }}assets/uploads/languages/{{App::getLocale()}}.png' width="30px" height="20px"/>
         </li>
         @foreach ($language as $language)
         <li>
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $language->code }}"/>
            <img class="border border-secondary" src='{{ asset($language->flag) }}' width="30px" height="20px" />
         </li>
         @endforeach
      </ul>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you mean the value from the inputs, and can you clarify your question please, you can see the value by inspecting each flag input...

Comment: make `type="checkbox"` and  `style="display:none"`

Comment: You can get or retrive the value in different way like `id, class, div,`

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You can use `document.querySelectorAll('li > input[type="hidden"]')[x].value` to get the value of the x-th hidden input . Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Please clarify your question. on which event you want to retrieve language code value? you want to get value of one flag? or want all values that loop through? 
explain your purpose where and how you want to use it. Then we can answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set id or class for input and then do this:

```
 var hidden=document.getElementsByClassName("input_class_name").value;
```

or

```
 var hidden=document.getElementsById("input_id").value;
```